# how to remove double quotes from the string result after performing addition or any calculation?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have 2 input fields with type text in html, the values are 2,200.01 and 5,000.02 and to perform addition I am navigating to controller to perform the addition

```
public Jsonresult TotalAssets(){
     Decimal check = Convert.ToDecimal(chequing) + Convert.ToDecimal(savTax);
    string totalAssets = check.ToString("#,##0.00"); //Now I get the result "7,200.03" .
return Json(totalAssets);
}
```

Now I pass this result back to html as response like below

```
   <script>
    function calculate() {
       
        var request;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            //New browsers.
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var formData = new FormData(document.forms.assets);
        }
        if (request != null) {
            var url = "Home/TotalAssets";
            request.open("POST", url, false);
            request.send(formData)
          
        }
    
        totalAssets.value = request.response;
    
    }
    </script>
```

Below is my html on page load calculate function from JS is called.

```
<form name="assets">
     <input type="text" value="2,200.01" name="chequing" id="chequing" />
<input type="text" value="5,000.02" name="totalAssets" id="totalAssets" />
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="totalAssets" id="totalAssets" />
</form>
```

and I see in the text box as well with double quotes. How do I remove these quotes and display only the numbers like 7,200.03  ?

Comment: `Now I pass this result back to html` show  this code, please

Comment: do you need to parse in javascript?

Comment: show us the signature of the c# action `Home/TotalAssets`

Comment: I have provided the code above. I am just missing a small stuff which I am not clear

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing each `"` occurence with nothing, effectively removing each double quote?

```
totalAssets = totalAssets.replace(/"/g, "")
```

Comment: Where to put this totalAssets = totalAssets.replace(/"/g, "") as it gives error ?

Comment: Could you please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code? It would be much easier. 

Comment: @Andrei there's no need for jsfiddle - Stack Overflow has pretty much all the same capabilities in Stack snippets.

Comment: is there any other way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I created an example for your question.
please consider that you can't have two elements with having the same `id`.
so I removed one of `totalAssets` elements and set the value to zero just for test.

in `HomeController` =

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult TotalAssets()
    {
        Decimal check = 7200.03m;
        string totalAssets = check.ToString("0.00"); 
        return Json(totalAssets);
    }
```

in `HTML` =

```
   <form name="assets">
    <input type="text" value="2,200.01" name="chequing" id="chequing" />
    <input type="text" value="0" name="totalAssets" id="totalAssets" />
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (totalAssets.value == 0) {
            calculate();
        }
    });

    function calculate() {

        var request;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            //New browsers.
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var formData = new FormData(document.forms.assets);
        }
        if (request != null) {
            var url = "Home/TotalAssets";
            request.open("POST", url, false);
            request.send(formData)
        }
         var decimalFormat = parseFloat(JSON.parse(request.response)).toFixed(2);
         totalAssets.value = numberWithCommas(decimalFormat);

    }


    function numberWithCommas(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
</script>
```

you can get decimal format(5000.00) with =

```
var decimalFormat = parseFloat(JSON.parse(request.response)).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: The reason it shows NaN is because reuest.response has , (comma) in the numbers like the number is "7,200.03". Only the quotes has to be ignored now

Comment: yes . string totalAssets = check.ToString("###0.00");

Comment: But I need 7,200.03 to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: If I remove comma then the whole purpose of me doing this is waste

Comment: As I told before I need the numbers with comma displayed on screen. But without double quotes which comes at the start and end of string and I have tried using substring but it chops the number instead of double quotes

Comment: It still displays NaN

Comment: string totalAssets = check.ToString("###0.00");  ---this gives result as "7200.03" . Double quotes will remain.
Now it goes back to javascript with this result and gives result as NaN

Comment: I updated the answer. I created an example for your question.

Comment: First thing I want to inform is if I have missed to write , the javascript will be called on load of the form and performs the calculation at the controller and returns the result back to form. So I dont have a button in my scenario.
Second is the format used in the javascript is not accepted to perform any calculation as the result is "7200.03" from the controller and with this format at JS it gives NaN

Comment: I don't have your code, so I just wrote an example for you. if you want an exact answer, please update your question and write your exact code.

Comment: I have edited and given all the details required for you to help me to find solution.

Comment: Yes this gives the answer. Is there a way to get decimal points along with comma ?
For example  2,000 + 3,000  gives 5,000 from this result but is there a way to get decimal 5,000.00 from numberWithCommas. As parseFloat when used on number is not giving me any decimal number